# Docker container is building but not showing the project's frontend pages on localhost

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker-compose

I am using Springboot for the backend, Angular for the frontend, and MySQL database. I am using docker-compose.yml for running the project. Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    container_name: mysql-db2 
    hostname: "sqlbox"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password2
ports:
  - "3307:3306"
restart: always

customerservice:                        
  image: customer-service               
  container_name: customer-service-app  
  build:
    context: .                          
    dockerfile: Backend/Dockerfile         
  ports:
     - "8080:8080"                     
  restart: always

depends_on: 
  - db                
environment:
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://sqlbox:3306/testdb1?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: password2

angular-service:
container_name: angularcont
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Frontend/Dockerfile
ports:
  - "4201:4200"
depends_on:                           #define dependencies of this app
  - customerservice
```

[This is the output I get after I start docker.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqAfn.png)

But when I go to localhost:8080/ or localhost:4200/ I can not see any pages.

Comment: You angular-service is running on port 4201, did you try that?

Comment: Yes, it is also not working.